# Cannot toggle class for button in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I want to make movement animation for `button` using class toggling just like in [this example](https://codepen.io/thetallweeks/pen/boinE). For some reasons my code is broken: it calls the click handler, but does not affect classes.

There's the code (I use React, Classnames and Webpack):

index.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./index.css";
import classnames from "classnames";

export default class PlaylistButton extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    alert("clicked");
    $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button className = {classnames(styles.button, styles.transform)} onClick = {() => this.onClick()}>label</button>
    );
  }
}
```

index.css:

```
.button {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #5266ed;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
}

.transform {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.transform-active {
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

What's the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `css-modules` will replace your classname with a random string in run time. So, the your expected class name for `styles.transform` will not be `transform` because it will be replaced with a random string. To answer your question, you need to use `styles.transform`and `styles.transform-active` in your jquery.

```
onClick() {
    alert("clicked");
    $('.'+ styles.transform ).toggleClass(styles.transform-active);
  }
```

css-modules will convert your classnames as the following.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe `toggleClass` argument needs to be replaced too?

Comment: @JustLogin Updated the answer.